How to Optimize Rolling Correlation Calculation Across All Column Pairs in a Large Pandas DataFrame
I want to compute the rolling Pearson correlation between all pairs of columns in a large Pandas DataFrame. Here's the current implementation I am using:
import itertools
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm

def pairwise_rolling_correlations_naive(df, window_size):
    column_pairs = list(itertools.combinations(df.columns, 2))
    results = {}
    for col1, col2 in tqdm(column_pairs):
        results[(col1, col2)] = df[col1].rolling(window=window_size).corr(df[col2])
    return pd.DataFrame(results)  # DataFrame with multi-level column index

While the .rolling().corr() method itself is quite fast, the overall performance is not satisfactory when dealing with dataframes that contain hundreds of columns (and thousands of rows).
Are there more efficient approaches or optimizations that can be applied to this function to handle large dataframes more effectively?

I've tried a few approaches and this is the fastest I've been able to get it.
It includes numba only to squeeze out a little more performance (when called repeatedly); most of the improvements come from the difference in approach.
When comparing the two approaches on a DataFrame having 300 cols and 3000 rows (window of 365), I find this one below to be about 30x faster.
@numba.njit()
def window_sum(x, w):
    c = np.cumsum(x)
    s = np.zeros(len(x) - w + 1)
    s[0] = c[w-1]
    s[1:] = c[w:] - c[:-w]
    return s

@numba.njit()
def rolling_correlation(x, y, w, x_mean, x_var, y_mean, y_var):
    xy = x * y
    xy_sum = window_sum(xy, w)
    xy_mean = xy_sum / w
    xy_cov = xy_mean - x_mean * y_mean
    correlation = xy_cov / np.sqrt(x_var * y_var)
    return correlation
    # return np.pad(correlation, (w-1, 0), mode='constant', constant_values=np.nan) # with padding

@numba.njit()
def precompute_means_vars(df_numpy, w):
    # precompute means and variances for the windows
    n_cols = df_numpy.shape[1]
    means = np.empty((n_cols, df_numpy.shape[0] - w + 1), dtype=df_numpy.dtype)
    varis = np.empty((n_cols, df_numpy.shape[0] - w + 1), dtype=df_numpy.dtype)
    
    for idx in range(n_cols):
        x = df_numpy[:, idx]
        x_sum = window_sum(x, w)
        x_mean = x_sum / w
        x_sq_sum = window_sum(x**2, w)
        x_var = x_sq_sum / w - x_mean**2
        means[idx] = x_mean
        varis[idx] = x_var
    
    return means, varis

def pairwise_rolling_correlations_fast(df, w):
    df_numpy = df.to_numpy()
    means, varis = precompute_means_vars(df_numpy, w)
    
    results = {}
    column_pairs = list(itertools.combinations(range(df_numpy.shape[1]), 2))
    for idx1, idx2 in tqdm(column_pairs):
        cc = rolling_correlation(df_numpy[:, idx1], df_numpy[:, idx2], w, means[idx1], varis[idx1], means[idx2], varis[idx2])
        results[(idx1, idx2)] = cc

    return pd.DataFrame(results) # df with multi-level column index


probably switching to float32 will have little effect on result and give some significant performance boost
